# Views in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Im developing a system with emberjs and it requires a lot of jquery plugins. 
For instance: I just need to make wysiwyg editor from div.

```
$('.summernote').summernote();
```

As I know I need to put this code like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend(Ember.TargetActionSupport, {
    templateName: 'views/block-view',
    didInsertElement: function() {
       $('.summernote').summernote(); //here
    }
});
```

So I need to create new view just for insert one line of code. Is it right way?

Comment: You should use components instead of views everything else looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use plain view here. First, views are going to be depreciated. Second, you would not have any gained value except the view itself. It's much more better and reusable to use components for such things.

Assuming that you have summernote in your bower files you can create a component like this:

```
SummernoteEditor = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$("textarea").summernote();
  }
});
```

And add a template for that component:

```
{{textarea value=text}}
```

Then, everywhere in your app you would use:

```
{{summernote-editor value=myValueProperty}}
```

Moreover, if you would end up needing some more flexibility using summernote, you could add actions and methods to your component. This way, you could e.g. send actions about updating, editing, etc. up to your controller.